# How to disconnect a Hibernate Session

Tags: java, hibernate

In my web app I use the *session-per-request* pattern. I have a connection pool and open sessions in a `Filter` using `SessionFactory.openSession()` and then `Session.close()`.

In the same app, for a complex process, I want to use *session-per-conversation*. I tried to open a second Session with `SessionFactory.openSession()`, but subsequently calling `Session.disconnect()` does nothing.

How can I manually connect/disconnect sessions? This is my Hibernate configuration file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost/.....</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">...</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">...</property>

    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.test_connection_on_checkout">true</property>

    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

The Java code:

```
longSession = mySessionFactory.openSession();
System.out.println(((SessionImplementor) longSession).isConnected());
longSession.disconnect();
System.out.println(((SessionImplementor) longSession).isConnected());
```

This outputs `true` twice...

Answer (score 1):

I think this is related to this note in [Hibernate Documents](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html):

> Note that disconnect() called on a session where the connection was
>   retrieved by Hibernate through its configured ConnectionProvider has
>   no effect, provided ConnectionReleaseMode.ON_CLOSE is not in effect

Also note to this in [Documentation for session-per-conversation:](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html)

> Committing a database transaction disconnects a session from the JDBC
>   connection and returns the connection to the pool

This say you need only to commit transactions to return the connection to the pool, except for the last transaction in your conversation:

```
// foo is an instance loaded earlier by the old session
Transaction t = session.beginTransaction(); // Obtain a new JDBC connection, start transaction

foo.setProperty("bar");

session.flush();    // Only for last transaction in conversation
t.commit();         // Also return JDBC connection
session.close();    // Only for last transaction in conversation
```

Comment: I know, but everywhere I read about session-per-conversation, but don't know what to actually call to use it. How should I configure Hibernate to be able to disconnect Session from Connection?

Comment: How should I open a session to be able to disconnect?

Comment: @Oliv I can't understand why you don't want to use `session.close()`?

Comment: Because once you close it, you can't reopen. You have to create a new one, and that is not long session. That's what we do now and it's pain in the ass to merge, save and delete objects in a complex graph of objects where single object is in multiple associations etc. I'd like to have a separate session for this conversation and flush/commit without having detached object.